# Is READYSTATE_LOADED across browsers?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been using valums file uploader for a long time: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

One problem I've had is that it never really hits 100% onProgress.

Once the file is done uploading, xhr.upload.onprogress is not fired anymore.
The next ping I get is the completion one at readyState 4.

This is because once 100% happens, there is processing on my server before the request completes. So the user really sees something like 98% followed by a "hang" of the request completing and then the "done" state after 100%.

readyState 2 is:

> READYSTATE_LOADED (2) The send method has been called. No data is
>   available yet.

Would it be reliable to start my processing state in the UI at that moment?

**Note** I'm curious if that would work in IE as well, although the uploader does a normal post in IE so we never have a progress bar for them.

Comment: Quirksmode suggests [*No*](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_r_2.html).

Comment: Are you referring to this article? http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_r_2.html I never think to check quirksmode - gotta do that more

Comment: Mouseover *No*, that's the link I'm referring to. Quirksmode was the only sane reference online for several years, I only worry about it aging without updates at this point.

Comment: We're both being funny cause I missed the "no" link and the link I sent you is def the same :D Anyway it looks to only suck for IE and Opera so I might be in luck for Chrome / FF / Safari where it is impacting me. But aside from the support of those browsers, does the "2" mean what I think. Does it mean I'm done sending up and now I'm just waiting for server? You should post as answer so I can mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Quirksmode:

> Explorer has a point in so far as the `load` event can be seen as a
>   subset of the `readystatechange` event. `load` fires when the page has
>   been loaded completely, which is equivalent to saying the **`readyState`
>   is 4: completed**.
>
> ...
>
> [However, E]xplorer doesn't support the `load` event on `xmlhttprequest`s. We
>   already knew this, but we should realize it doesn't even allow you to
>   set the event handler, since it allows only a very limited set of
>   properties on the `xmlhttp` object.
>
> The `event` object is still missing in Opera, though not in Mozilla.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_r_2.html