# How can I tell XHR is sent to server using readyState?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This question is related to my prior question:
[Is READYSTATE_LOADED across browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495286/is-readystate-loaded-across-browsers)

So I know that readyState is not reliable across browsers. I'm currently just trying to do a proof-of-concept in ANY browser at this point.

I'm in my plugin and have code like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){            

  if (xhr.readyState == 4){
      self._onComplete(id, xhr);                    
  }
  else if (xhr.readyState == 2 ){
    self._onSent( id, xhr );
  }

};
```

If I log the callbacks, "sent" fires immediately before "complete", AFTER my server side script responds. Am I misunderstanding what readyState 2 is? I tried 1 for kicks and that didn't fire before the server responded either.

I took a look into the upload object of the xhr object, which does at least have a "progress" event, but I still didn't see anything about progress being done. In fact if the last progress was at 97%, it will not fire at 100% as the file completes sending to server. Therefore while the server processes the upload, the progress hangs at 97% before the readyState becomes 4.

This makes the user think the upload stalled even thought it actually went up all the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no state to check to see when a request has been sent off.

`readyState` 2 means that the server has responded and all headers have come in. This is fired right before the main body section of the request comes in.

Your best bet is to fire your own event when you issue the `send()` command.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){            

  if (xhr.readyState == 4){
      self._onComplete(id, xhr);                    
  }
  else if (xhr.readyState == 2 ){
    // Headers received
  }

};

xhr.send(data)
self._onSend( id, xhr );
```

> 4.6 States
>
> UNSENT (numeric value 0) The object has been constructed.
>
> OPENED (numeric value 1) The open() method has been successfully
>   invoked. During this state request headers can be set using
>   setRequestHeader() and the request can be made using the send()
>   method.
>
> HEADERS_RECEIVED (numeric value 2) All redirects (if any) have been
>   followed and all HTTP headers of the final response have been
>   received. Several response members of the object are now available.
>
> LOADING (numeric value 3) The response entity body is being received.
>
> DONE (numeric value 4) The data transfer has been completed or
>   something went wrong during the transfer (e.g. infinite redirects).

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#states

**EDIT**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){            

  if (xhr.readyState == 4){
      self._onComplete(id, xhr);                    
  }
  else if (xhr.readyState == 2 ){
    // Headers received
  }
  else if (xhr.readyState == 1 ){
    // xhr.open() called
    // You can set headers here amoung other things
    xhr.send(data)
    self._onSend( id, xhr );
  }

};

xhr.open(method, url, async, user, password)
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method

Comment: Ah where I was reading it was much less clear about the states. If I do something when .send goes off, isn't that just when like the first byte goes off rather than 100% of bytes?

Comment: I'd like to mark your answer as the one, but can you answer my question about .send?

Comment: Ah sorry, missed your comment. If you do as the example I give in my answer your will be firing around the same time the first byte is sent off. As far as the spec is layed out by w3, there is no way to deterime when a request is sent off. States 0 and 1 open tell you when things are started. If you where to use `xhr.open()` you'd get a `xhr.readyState` equal to 1, but that does not send off the request. I'll update my answer to show an example.